# How to create SVG file using hexSticker

Tags: r, image-processing, svg

I have the following code, which produces PNG file using [hexSticker](https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/hexSticker):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexSticker)

p <- ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt), data = mtcars) + geom_point()
p <- p + theme_void() + theme_transparent()

sticker(p, package="hexSticker", p_size=8, s_x=1, s_y=.75, s_width=1.3, s_height=1,filename="test.png")
```

It produces the following PNG file:

[image]

How can I make the SVG version of it?

At the end of the day I'd like to submit the figure to **[GitHub hexbin](https://github.com/maxogden/hexbin)**, 
so it needs to meet it standard.

Comment: check `?svg` to save as svg

Comment: don't really like how the code was implemented for `hexSticker::sticker`. If you can't display it on your graphical device to do a `svg`, you may need to edit out the line `save_sticker(filename, sticker)` from the `sticker` function and write the sticker object out directly.

Comment: Alernatively, flag the issue to the author and ask for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexSticker)

p <- ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt), data = mtcars) + geom_point()
p <- p + theme_void() + theme_transparent()

sticker(
        p
      , package="hexSticker"
      , p_size=8
      , s_x=1
      , s_y=.75
      , s_width=1.3
      , s_height=1
      ,filename="test.svg"
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an [online converter to convert png to svg](https://www.aconvert.com/image/png-to-svg/) (took about 20 seconds to upload, convert, download).